# VS Code stage changes shortcut

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, git-stage

What is the VS Code `stage changes` shortcut?

I mean is it possible to stage a selected file without clicking the plus button in the version control tab?

[image]

Maybe there is no shortcut an it is somehow possible to setup one?

Comment: Additional note for anyone who struggled with the accepted answer, note that you need to OPEN the file to be staged in the diff editor (where you compare the versions of the file before and after the change), with your cursor active in the diff editor. Once there, the keyboard shortcuts to stage/unstage that you set will work. In the keyboard shortcuts settings, note that the default is to have the keybinding active when "isInDiffEditor" is true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`git.Stage` and `git.StageAll`. They have no keybinding assigned by default. You can assign a custom one in your keyboard shortcut settings. <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: Could you, please, let me know how did you find the commands? Did you just checked the settings shortcuts or did you read a manual somewhere?

Comment: Opening your keyboard settings like mentioned above will bring up a search field. I typed "stage" in there to filter for the relevant commands. Alternatively, if you want to view all Git commands, type "git".
Also incredibly useful is the keyboard icon on the right end of that search field. Click on that and enter any keyboard shortcut and VS Code will list all the commands currently attached to that.

Comment: This didn't work for me without selecting the file in scm using a mouse click. Selecting with keyboard only then using the keyboard shortcut didn't have any effect

Comment: `git.Stage` works on an **open file or comparison**, not a filename in the SCM view.

Answer (score 23):

### My custom workflow:

1. Open the SCM view `ctrl+shift+G`
2. Select the file in SCM using `up/down arrow keys`
3. Diff the file `spacebar`
4. Stage the file `ctrl+up`
5. Diff the file `spacebar`
6. Stage the file `ctrl+up`

#### How to configure?

Preferences: Open Keyboard shortcuts (JSON) `command: workbench.action.openGlobalKeybindingsFile`
Then put in the following:

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+up",
        "command": "git.stage",
        "when": "workbench.scm.active"
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

for those who interested in **stageAll / unstageAll**, you can also do these as well

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+up",
        "command": "git.stageAll",
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+down",
        "command": "git.unstageAll",
    }
]
```

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>/<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)
3. Place your key bindings

Answer (score 2):

I know you are looking for a keyboard shortcut and I was too.  However, I have found that the use of the command palette is a much more efficient and cleaner workflow:

1. open command palette <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.
2. type in "git stage".

I offer this as an alternative if anyone is looking.